# How do I find build.properties in eclipse root directory

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to `import` my eclipse Java project too Visual studio code using `WPILib`, where it’s asking me to select `build.properties` file in the root directory of my eclipse project. However there is no such file. Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: build.properties is only for Eclipse plug-in projects, a plain Java project won't have one.

Comment: The Java language support in VS Code is a headless Eclipse. Why do you have to import it at all instead of just open the project?